# How to edit a mounted HDD

Tags: partitioning, disk

I want to know why my HDD main partition (the biggest part of the disk) appears as it was a double partition:

[image: HDD Partitions]

Can I change it? How?

Also, LibreOffice 5 doesn't recognize that partition. It only let me read and write files from the System partition. Why? How could I fix it? ???

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!!!!!

Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **MBR** scheme has been used to partition your disk.

This means partitions are limited to 4 primary partitions. To overcome that, the **extended** partition scheme has been created; inside which one can create other **logical** partition.

What you see is the extended partition #2 with one logical partition inside (#5).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and data!!! Please, forgive my full ignorance about this topic.